# Create matrix in R by specifying diagonals

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to find the most efficient way to create the following matrix.

```
> t(A)
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]
 [1,]    0 1.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
 [2,]    0 0.125 0.875 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
 [3,]    0 0.000 0.250 0.750 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
 [4,]    0 0.000 0.000 0.375 0.625 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
 [5,]    0 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.500 0.500 0.000 0.000 0.000
 [6,]    0 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.625 0.375 0.000 0.000
 [7,]    0 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.750 0.250 0.000
 [8,]    0 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.875 0.125
 [9,]    0 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000
```

With `NumPy` I'm used to do it by filling the upper and lower diagonals. However, I can't find the equivalent functions in R. So I am wondering if there is a a way that creates that matrix without having to manually enter the numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = seq(0,1,0.125)
m = diag(x)
m[col(m)==row(m)+1]=rev(x[-1])
m
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]
 [1,]    0 1.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
 [2,]    0 0.125 0.875 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
 [3,]    0 0.000 0.250 0.750 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
 [4,]    0 0.000 0.000 0.375 0.625 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
 [5,]    0 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.500 0.500 0.000 0.000 0.000
 [6,]    0 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.625 0.375 0.000 0.000
 [7,]    0 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.750 0.250 0.000
 [8,]    0 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.875 0.125
 [9,]    0 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the most efficient way, but I hope it is what you are looking for.

```
CorM <- matrix(nrow = 9, ncol = 9)
CorM[upper.tri(CorM, diag = TRUE)] <- 
  c(0,
    1, 0.125,
    0, 0.875, 0.250,
    0, 0, 0.750, 0.375,
    0, 0, 0, 0.625, 0.500,
    rep(0, 4), 0.500, 0.625,
    rep(0, 5), 0.375, 0.750,
    rep(0, 6), 0.250, 0.875,
    rep(0, 7), 0.125, 1.00
   )
CorM[lower.tri(CorM, diag = FALSE)] <- 
  c(rep(0, 36))

CorM
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]
 [1,]    0 1.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
 [2,]    0 0.125 0.875 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
 [3,]    0 0.000 0.250 0.750 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
 [4,]    0 0.000 0.000 0.375 0.625 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
 [5,]    0 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.500 0.500 0.000 0.000 0.000
 [6,]    0 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.625 0.375 0.000 0.000
 [7,]    0 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.750 0.250 0.000
 [8,]    0 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.875 0.125
 [9,]    0 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any function that does this in a generic way.

My solution is through looping:

```
ma <- matrix(0, ncol = 9, nrow = 9)
rate = 0.125

for(i in 1:nrow(ma)){

  for(j in 1:ncol(ma)){

    if(i == j){ 
      ma[i,j] = rate*(i-1)

    } else if(j == i + 1){
      ma[i,j] = 1 - rate*(i-1)
    }
  }
}

ma
```